# Redirect 301 not working htaccess laravel

Tags: laravel, .htaccess, redirect

Currently I have this working sample link

`https://sample.com/product-landing?id=1`

but on site:google.com

it is detected as `https://sample.com/product-landing?id=1/homebrewing`

now I'm trying to redirect it like this

`Redirect 301 /product-landing?id=1/homebrewing https://sample.com/product-landing?id=1`

but it's not working

my other redirect codes like this

`Redirect 301 /wine https://sample.com/mybeer`

is working properly. How come?

Comment: Is this for one specific URL only?

Comment: Try `ErrorDocument 301 https://sample.com/mybeer`

Comment: Yes this is for specific url only